# Rxjava + Retrofit get FATAL Exception: RxCachedThreadScheduler

Tags: android, retrofit, rx-java, retrofit2, rx-java2

Here's the code:

```
Observable.combineLatest(observable1, observable2,observable3, observable4,observable5,new Function5<>())
```

When one or sevral observables return code = 404,I throw exception

```
 return Observable.error(
                    new RxApiException(tHttpResult.getCode(), tHttpResult.getMessage()));
```

And I will get

```
FATAL EXCEPTION : RxCachedThreadScheduler-3
```

How to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to define how you handle errors. If no `onError` handler is set up for the consumer of the Observable it gets forwarded to the Uncaught Exception Handler for the executing thread instead.

On android the exception handler causes a fatal exception when triggered, closing the application.

Either define a way that error should be handled or use `RxJavaPlugins.registerErrorHandler(...)` to define how unhandled exceptions should be processed for your entire application.